# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/2+\dots+\sqrt{1/n}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find
>    $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}}$$

How to evaluate this?

Comment: The value seems to converge to 1.521890386864232, though it is not apparent that this number should have any neat closed form expression

Comment: Note that
$$
\begin{align}
e &= 1 + 1 + \frac 1{2!} + \frac 1{3!} + \cdots \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac 1{2}(1 + \frac 1{3}(1 + \cdots ))
\end{align}
$$ Perhaps that helps somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may not be trivial. See [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html) and [Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html).